# UIScrollView viewForZoomingInScrollView when pagingEnabled with multiple UIImageViews in it

Tags: uiscrollview

I have this UIScrollView with pagingEnabled to let the user page between some images.
Now I want to let the user zoom on each one of the images. How do I do that? What I have now zooms on my UIScrollView from its origin and I need it to zoom on each picture, not the hole UIScrollView.

What I have now:

```
UIScrollView* containerView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];

containerView.scrollEnabled = YES;
containerView.pagingEnabled = YES;

[containerView setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
[containerView setDelegate:self];
self.view = containerView;

UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:image01];
UIImageView *viewOne = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageOne];

viewOne.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 480);
[containerView addSubview:viewOne];

UIImage *imageTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:image02];
UIImageView *viewTwo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageTwo];
viewTwo.frame = CGRectMake(320, 44, 320, 480);
[containerView addSubview:viewTwo];

UIImage *imageThree = [UIImage imageNamed:image03];
UIImageView *viewThree = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageThree];
viewThree.frame = CGRectMake(640, 44, 320, 480);
[containerView addSubview:viewThree];

- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)containerView
{
    return containerView;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to return a view contained in your scrool. As you have 3 UIImage, try with this...

In .h

```
UIView *auxView;
```

In .m

```
...
[auxView addSubview:imageOne];
[auxView addSubview:imageTwo];
[auxView addSubview:imageThree];

[containerView addSubview:auxView];
}

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)containerView{
return auxView;   }
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to zoom each `UIImageView` individually, right?

I was struggling with this problem many weeks, then I decide to wrote a class to solve this problem.
Here is my github repo of this class: https://github.com/windmemory/PhotoCollectionView

My solution to this problem is to create single `UIScrollView` to contain every `UIImageView`, and then add these `UIScrollView` to the `containerView`.

If we add all the `UIImageView` to a single view then make it zoomable, when we zoom one photo, all these photos will be zoomed, then the `contentSize` will change accordingly. Once the `contentSize` is changed, it will messed up all the paging thing. So the best way I came up is to use `UIScrollView` to contain `UIImageView`, then put every `UIScrollView` into the `containerView`, this will allow you to zoom each photo separately, which won't mess up all the paging thing you set up.

Hope this may help you.